# Selecting / modifying Python docstrings in Vim

Tags: python, vim

Consider the below function definition:

```
def function(self, arg1, arg2):
    """Function for doing something.

    Args:
         arg1: Argument 1.
         arg2: Argument 2.
    Returns:
         Returns something.
    """
    ...
    ...
```

What would the easiest way of selecting the whole docstring be? For example, I can easily select the inner and outer perimeters of a function using built-in square bracket mappings (i.e. `[m` or `]m`), but what about the docstrings themselves? The best I can do now is using square-bracket mappings to jump to the beginning of a function definition, going down a line, then manually highlighting using visual-mode selection. Assuming my cursor is within the function block, this is how I would approach docstring selection:

1. `[m` to go to beginning of function definition
2. `j` to go down a line
3. `V` to go to line-wise visual mode
4. `{n}j` to go down whatever the relative-line number of last `"""` is

Is there any way of making this easier? I think at least there must be some workaround for step 4 which can be quite tedious. Perhaps some pattern matching? `g*` for selection was an idea I had but it only works if the triple quotation marks are isolated in their own line.

Comment: That's a docstring, not a comment.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Oops. Thank you for clarifying. I edited the question appropriately.

Comment: I am very happy you found the `[m` and other "method" mappings. I find these to be very under utilized.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making a docstring text-object. Like `id`/`ad`.

Put the following in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
function! s:docstring(...)
    call search('^\s*def.*\n\s*\zs"""\_s*.', 'bc' . (a:0 ? 'e' : ''))
    normal! m<
    if a:0
        call search('.\ze\_s*"""', 'e')
    else
        call search('"""', 'e')
        call search('"""', 'e')
    endif
    normal! m>
    normal! `<v`>
endfunction

xnoremap <buffer> id :<c-u>call <SID>docstring(1)<cr>gv
xnoremap <buffer> ad :<c-u>call <SID>docstring()<cr>gv
onoremap <buffer> id :normal vid<cr>
onoremap <buffer> ad :normal vad<cr>
```

Now you can do use the `id`/`ad` text-objects as you would any Vim text objects.

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty:

```
nmap <f10> [m/"""<cr>vn
```

in function/method body, press `<f10>` will select docstring.

Comment: there is `[m` @phd